# How to pipe output of command to two separate commands and store outputs

Tags: bash, io-redirection, sort, tee, optimization

I have a really long command that runs over a huge file and I am forced to run it twice which doubles the time it takes to run.

This is what I am doing at the moment:

```
x=$(command | sort -u)
y=$(command | sort -n)
```

I was wondering whether there is any way to redirect the output of command to both `sort -u` and `sort -n` and store output of each into separate variables or files like I did above with `x` and `y`.

I tried to use tee to do the following but no luck:

```
command | tee >(sort -n > x.txt) >(sort -u > y.txt)
```

I tried to redirect output to text files but it just printed it to standard output instead.

Any tips or ideas?

Comment: are you sure it didn't print to standard output *as well* rather than *instead*?

Comment: Oh you're right. I don't want it to print it to standard output though

Comment: You could just discard standard output by redirecting it to `/dev/null`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're really close

```
command | tee >(sort -n >/tmp/x.txt) | sort -u >/tmp/y.txt
```

In case you're curious, the `>( ... )` action gets replaced with a path to the descriptor pipe (eg `/dev/fd/1234`), so the resulting pipeline has this shape, with `/dev/fd/1234` being attached to the other `sort` command

```
command | tee /dev/fd/1234 | sort > /path/to/elsewhere
```

To capture `sort`ed output into a variable (from [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/616697/how-to-pipe-output-of-command-to-two-separate-commands-and-store-outputs/616701#comment1153411_616701), not from question)

```
var=$(command | tee >(sort -n > x.txt) >(sort -u > y.txt) | sort -u)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response!! Do you know if I could redirect output to a variable as well or just a file? Rest of my code works with variables so it'll make my life easier haha.

Comment: What would you want put into the variable?

Comment: The output of sort -n and sort -u. Above you redirected it to text files but I was wondering if there is a way to store it into a variable instead perhaps.

Comment: You can put the output of _one_ of those streams into a variable but not both simultaneously. Revert to the original code in your question and capture the output `v="$( your_command )"`

Comment: Makes sense! with your original solution, I get /dev/fd/63: Permission denied. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: You're not literally writing `/dev/fd/63` anywhere are you? If so, don't do that

Comment: No I am not. Just did exactly what you said in your answer.